# I am getting an error when i try to do a Looping String in Python

Tags: python, string, loops

New to Programming. Currently learning Python.

Code I wrote is:

```
       x = 0
       for x in "Helper":
       x = x + 1
       print(x)
```

But i get an error message saying "TypeError: cannot concatenate 'str' and 'int' objects on line 82"

Can anyone explain what i did wrong?

Comment: line 82 would be "x = x +1"

Comment: What exactly do you believe `x = x + 1` should do in this case?

Comment: The core problem is that you are overloading the `x` variable.  In your loop, `x` will have each letter of the string, one at a time, hiding the one to which you assigned 0.  So, first time through you're trying to do `x = 'H' + 1`, which is not valid.

Comment: Do `print(x)` inside the loop to see what its value is. You use the same `x` for the number and the loop variable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the comments say, don't use "x" for BOTH variables.

Do something like this:

```
x = 0
for c in "Helper":
   x = x + 1
print(x)
```

Result:

```
6
```

which is the number of characters in the string "Helper".

Answer (score 0):

`x` is initialized as int, but you are trying to add two different type (int, string) you should match each type

so try this

```py
y = ""
for x in "Helper":
    y = y + x
print(y)
```